# Removing bin executable folder from GitHub

Tags: git, github

I accidentally pushed the `bin` folder of my Java program to GitHub, and now I wish to remove all those `.class` files.

How can I do that?

Comment: [git rm](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First, you should create a commit that removes this folder from git:

```
$ git rm -r bin
$ git commit -m "Removed bin folder"
$ git push origin master
```

After doing that, you can ensure this mistake won't happen again by adding the `bin` directory to your `.gitignore` file, and commit that change too:

```
$ echo "bin/" >> .gitignore
$ git add .gitignore
$ git commit -m "Added bin folder to gitignore"
$ git push origin master
```

Comment: `git rm -r bin` might be required most of the times